# Can't remove the scroll bar of a scroll area in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have creted this page in html & css. I have a section with a scroll bar inside the page  and for small size it appears like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qomBV.png)
I don't want 2 scrollbars to be there so I want to remove the scrollbar of this section for small sizes. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="account-left">
  <div class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0">
    <div class="section">
      <!--<h1 style="color:black;">{{hais}}</h1>-->
      <div style="text-align: center; background: #eee;">
        <span ng-show="tasklist.options.no_tasks" ng-bind-html="tasklist.options.no_tasks.message"></span>
      </div>
     <ul>
<li >Print smth</li>
<li >Print smth</li>
<li >Print smth</li>
</ul>

      <a class="loadmore" ng-hide="1" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="loadMore(loadvalue, activeTab)">Load more</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since I have a scroll-area, I cant make it hide-sm because this removes all the area of scrolling and I want to remove only the scroll bar.Is there any way? Thanks.I'm using bootstrap.

After inserted this to my code like in the answer below:

```html
<div class="account-left">
  <div style=" width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-right: 17px;">
    <div class="section">
      //etc the same part of code which is above
```

My result is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQbVF.png)

But no scrolling

Comment: How can we test your code? It's incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

try this in css

```
your_div { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

Comment: if it is don't work try this : 
your_div { overflow-y: hidden !important; }

Comment: Ok this works, but removes the area doesnt scroll anymore even for big page. I want it to scroll without the scroll bar for small size

Answer (score 0):

```
.yourdiv {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

.yourdiv::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}
```

Assuming that your other styles about div's and containers are correct, this should work.

To know more about this topic visit this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kurlak/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari/). There is a clear explanation of how browsers work with scrollbars and how can we hide them in a cross-browser compatibility approach. In case of my solution doesn't work, I'm almost sure you will find your solution over the link explanation.

Comment: So you say I should remove the class="scroll-area" and data-spy and then insert this?

Comment: Yes sir. I think this works out. To test it I think you should use more text and more lines as well, to make sure you test the scroll :) 
I'm not 100% I understood what you need to do. If this doesn't work, please tell me in detail your main objective.

Comment: Ok after inserted that there is no more scrolling, but I want the area to scroll but without scroll bar for small size of screen.

Comment: hmmm... you sure there is no scrolling? We are forcing the overflow-y to be 'scroll'. Make sure no parent nodes have overflow-x or overflow-y.
If you confirm everything is correct, can you do a quick jsfiddle for me to take a look? I'm at work, I don't have much time to do it myself :)

Comment: Ok, I see the result. U want to remove the vertical scrollbar right? Horizontal scroll does not matter right?

Comment: Yeap that is what i WANT

Comment: Editing my answer.

Comment: The same result again

Comment: Then is probably some div css position / width / height problem. Check the link I sent to you to understand how you can control the scrollbars and div's.